Google API refresh token without user interaction
So I have this code ( it is something i found around google ):
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uris[0]
  );

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);        
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token))
    callback(oAuth2Client);  
  });
}
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", code => {
    rl.close();  
  oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {    
      if (err) return console.error("Error retrieving access token", err);      
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), error => {
        if (error) return console.error(error);
        console.log("Token stored to", TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
  })

People claim that this is the way to get refresh token and after that generate new token.json file. BUT this works if I copy the url generate console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url:", authUrl); and create the token by myself. I don't understand how to use this newly generated authUrl to automatically get the token and create the token.json file in the runtime. Followed all the google documentation I found about this matter but it is simply not understandable. Also saw many posts with similar lack of knowledge. Will be very grateful if someone finally explain this.
